# Scala NumberFormatException when converting a String to Long?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Our app is Scala-based and built on the Play! framework. I've generated a random number using Scala Random. This is to use as a unique key for each account in our app.

However, when I go to save the new account into the database, it throws a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`:

**More Info:** I'm converting a string of an account ID to a Scala Long. I'm looking it up using a Squeryl object, grabbing the ID, and then converting it. Here's what it looks like:

`val account_id = Account.findAccountByUnique(account.uniqueKey).id.toLong`

This is what findAccountByUnique looks like:

```
def findAccountByUnique(criteria: String) = {
    from(DB.accounts)(a =>
      where(a.uniqueKey == criteria)
        select (a))
  }
```

The stack trace on error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "468b68c"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:209)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
        at controllers.Accounts$.save(Accounts.scala:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:496)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
        at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:257)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
        at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've typecasted the unique key as both a Scala `Long` and `String` but it throws the same error. Any idea as to a fix?

Comment: If you obtain a series of random numbers, they will not necessarily be unique.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What more information do you need? Since your comment, I even tried it with a java.UUID (very unique) and it throws the same error.

Comment: *"What more information do you need?"*  Which part of S-S-C-C-E are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I don't know what more I can post! When I run through this with IntelliJ I get as deep as compiled code where it's impossible to debug! The only symptom is the stack trace!

Comment: If it's *showing* letters, that means it's trying to *parse* letters. Your claim that "only numbers are generated" is incorrect in terms of the value which is being parsed. As for what more you can post: a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. You haven't posted *any* code, let alone a complete program.

Comment: I've added the trouble code. If I were to post more I'd start posting Squeryl and PrimitiveTypeMode, there's really not a lot of code to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it looks like there was a database helper returning junk data. Essentially it was actually returning its own "sample" data which happened to be a hexadecimal. It was a lib in Squeryl, looks like something was malformed somewhere and therefore it triggered a "sample" response.

Looks like because `account.uniqueKey` had been updated from a previous query, it brought some junk with it. Still investigating how it happened but at least I found the real problem.

Answer (score 5):

To convert a hexadecimal number to a decimal one there is `java.lang.Long.parseLong`:

```
scala> import java.lang.{ Long => JLong }
import java.lang.{Long=>JLong}

scala> JLong.parseLong("468b68c", 16)
res8: Long = 73971340
```

Another way to convert hex to decimal, is to write your own method:

```
def toHex(s: String): Long = {
  val Hex = "([0-9a-fA-F]+)".r
  s match {
    case Hex(_) => java.lang.Long.parseLong(s, 16)
    case _ => throw new NumberFormatException("invalid hex number: " + s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks ike this will do the trick, my only concern is why is a hexadecimal being returned? This is a test DB where the max ID is 14. Thanks!

Comment: @DeLonge: You asked for a way to convert a string to a hexadecimal number and I showed you a way. If you have further requirements you have to tell them.

Comment: That wasn't the case at all. It was Joop's answer that pointed out the hexadecimal issue. Problems are always evolving and if you can't comment any more then please kindly say so.

Answer (score 0):

Id is in hexadecimal, so you need

```
val account_id = Account.findAccountByUnique(account.uniqueKey).id.toLong(16)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it triggered a compiler error. But I think there's some Scala "magic" going on. `scala.this.Predef.augmentString(org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.singleColumnQuery2RightHandSideOfIn[models.Account](models.Account.findAccountByUnique(account.uniqueCode)).id).toLong of type Long does not take parameters`

Comment: Reason why I say magic is if I remove that entire line, suddenly I have access to the proper account ID when I access account.id. It must be a Squeryl "super object" doing something somewhere, cause there's no logical code looking up the key in the account object.

Comment: I had extrapolated that as toLong probably uses java's parseLong(), there would exist a toLong(int base). Sorry